# StrongLoop: mutual Model Relations

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I have this app with 3 Models: Users, Events and Venues.

An user can create events that take places in a venue, This are the relations:

User: hasMany Event

Venue: hasMany Event

Event: belongsTo User

But I'm not sure if Event must also belongsTo Venue? (as the Venue is not the owner of the Event)

---

<strike>Also, a more advance Question. If I create another Model: Dates... so an Event can have multiple Dates, should I use *Events EmbedsMany Dates*? or is better to use *Events hasMany Dates* and *Dates belongsTo Event*? What's the difference?</strike> --> Asked in a new question by request here: [StrongLoop: EmbedsMany vs hasMany and belongTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886200/strongloop-embedsmany-vs-hasmany-and-belongto)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd be interested in the answer to your second question, but you should create a new question for it.

Comment: Ok @conradj , here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886200/strongloop-embedsmany-vs-hasmany-and-belongto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it useful to think of creating relationships as extending your API endpoints. If you want an endpoint like `api/Events/{eventid}/Venue` then create the belongsTo relationship to Venue in Event.